# What would be the right fcntl flags?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, file-descriptor, fcntl

What would be the right fcntl flags when reading from a disk and writing to a file over the **network** for best speed?

perhaps the issues is with the fcntl flags set on the file descriptor?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `fcntl` offers you anything that would affect performance. Perhaps you're looking for `posix_fadvise`, but I think the main key is just to use reasonably large buffers.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using NFS (or something like that) to read/write to a file across the network. The best option is to read/write as large as necesssary parts of the file. Then the NFS has more options as to dividing the data up into the larger size packets - hence less overhead in terms of the network stack.